# Which one is faster? O(2^n) or O(n!)

Tags: math, time-complexity

I'm studying algorithm complexity and I am trying to figure out this one question that runs in my mind- is O(n!) faster than O(2^n) or is it the opposite way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`O(2^n)` is `2 * 2 * 2 * ...` where `O(n!)` is `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ...`

`O(n!)` will quickly grow much larger - so `O(2^n)` is faster.

For example: `2^10 = 1024` and `10! = 3628800`

Comment: yes, but if we take for instance n=3 that O(2^n) is 8 whereas O(n!) is 6, which means that with a small n value, O(2^n) is faster than O(n!).. that is what confuses me here

Comment: @Integrity  Big-O notation means *..as N approaches infinity.*  so it doesn't matter with the small values of N, it matter what happens as N gets large.

Answer (score 1):

You can try working with *Stirling's approximation* for `n!`
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

```
 n! = (n / e)^n * sqrt(2 * Pi * n) * (1 + o(n))
```

Now, let's compare

```
 O(n!) <=> O(2^n)
```

In order to find out the right letter `<`, `=` or `>` let's compute *limit*

```
 lim (n! / 2^n) =
   n -> +inf

 lim (n / e)^n * sqrt(2 * pi * n) / 2^n >=
   n -> +inf

 lim n^n / (2 * e)^n >= // when n > 4 * e
   n -> +inf

 lim (4 * e)^n / (2 * e)^n =
   n -> +inf 

 lim 2^n = +inf
   n -> +inf
```

So

```
 lim (n! / 2^n) = +inf
   n -> +inf
```

which means that `O(n!) > O(2^)`